# How to create a prescription pill count like pain management facilities use?

Tags: python

I don't understand why this code won't work.  I want to create some code to help me know exactly how many pills need to be taken back to pain management.  If you don't take the right amount back, then you get kicked out of pain management.  So I'm just wanting to create a script that will help me so I don't take too few back.

As anyone can tell.  I don't have any experience with Python.  I just installed it and tried using the documentation to aide in completing what I thought would be a trivial script.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\howell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\pill_count.py", line 17, in <module>
    date1 = datetime.date(datetime.strptime((str(year) + "-" + str(starting_Month) + "-" + str(starting_Month) + "-" + str(starting_Day)), '%Y-%m-%d'))
  File "C:\Users\howell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\_strptime.py", line 510, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Users\howell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\_strptime.py", line 346, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: -1
```

```
How many pills did you have left?   12
How many pills did you get?   90
How many pills do you take?    6
Starting Month, Type 1 for January, 2 for February, etc.9
Starting Day; Type 1-311
Ending Month, Type 1 for January, 2 for February, etc.10
Starting Day; Type 1-3131
Taking 6 a day, you should have 102 left.

# dates are easily constructed and formatted
#from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from datetime import datetime

year = 2016
left_over_pill_count = input('How many pills did you have left?   ')
new_prescription = input('How many pills did you get?   ')
total_pills = int(left_over_pill_count) + int(new_prescription)
daily_pill_intake = input('How many pills do you take?    ')
starting_Month = input('Starting Month, Type 1 for January, 2 for February, etc.')
starting_Day = input('Starting Day; Type 1-31')
ending_Month = input('Ending Month, Type 1 for January, 2 for February, etc.')
ending_Day = input('Starting Day; Type 1-31')


# count number of days until next doctors appointment
date1 = datetime.date(datetime.strptime((str(year) + "-" + str(starting_Month) + "-" + str(starting_Day)), '%Y-%m-%d'))
date2 = datetime.date(datetime.strptime((str(year) + "-" + str(ending_Month) + "-" + str(ending_Day)), '%Y-%m-%d'))

#date_count = (date2 - date1)
#total_days = date_count

# fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
#fmt = '%d'
#d1 = datetime.strptime(date1, fmt)
#d2 = datetime.strptime(date2, fmt)

# print (d2-d1).days * 24 * 60

for i in range(1, (date1-date2).days):
    total_pills = total_pills - int(daily_pill_intake)
    print(total_pills)

print("Taking " + str(daily_pill_intake) + " a day, you should have " + str(total_pills) + " left.")
```

Comment: "Won't work" doesn't really help track down the issue, you should edit the question to include the error. But I imagine `total_pills = int(left_over_pill_count + new_prescription)` gives you an unintended output. You need to call `int` on both inputs separately before adding them

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
date1 = datetime.date(datetime.strptime((str(year) + "-" + str(starting_Month) + "-" + str(starting_Month) + "-" + str(starting_Day)), '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

You're telling `datetime.strptime` to parse a string of the form "year-month-day", but the string you give it is of the form "year-month-month-day"; you included the month twice!  The same problem applies to the next line as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.  My eyes are not picking up anything.  I made the changes and got it to kind of work.  Well, it's not throwing exceptions but it is not producing the right output.  It's producing a negative number.

Comment: The for loop is not running at all.  It just returns the total_pill count without ever subtracting the number of daily pills that is taken.

Comment: @KevinHowell: That seems like it should be asked about in a separate question.